# prepositions with a long period of time

Tags: prepositions

> Thank you for your patience over the last 15 weeks whilst we build this road

Can I replace the **over** by **during** or **in** and if I can, is it making any difference then?

The previous question in this regard didn't get a thorough explanation about over and during being used with a period of time. Some indicated when during are used with a period of time, it has connotation that thing happened intermittently, but in fact I can find many instances contradict this viewpoint, saying, wages have fallen by more than twenty percent **during** the past two months...and interesting thing is we have a analogous sentence in which over is used, the number of attacks on the capital had gone down ***over*** the past week...

My goal is to make the difference between them clearer rather than ambiguous results got in that post.

Answer (score 2):

You could replace **over** with **during** in that sentence, but to my ear not with **in**.   Minor changes can have a significant impact on which prepositions are idiomatic.  It is difficult to state a rule of thumb which would let you distinguish which situations license which prepositions.

> Thanks for your patience over the last fifteen weeks while we  built this road. <sup>OK</sup>
>
> Thanks for your patience during the last fifteen weeks while we built this road. <sup>OK</sup>
>
> Thanks for your patience in the last fifteen weeks while we built this road.  <sup>marginal</sup>
>
> We thank you for your patience especially in the final week of this fifteen week effort, when traffic was reduced to a crawl. <sup>OK</sup>

Which prepositions are idiomatic could change when **three weeks** is replaced with some activity that takes time, and **patience** is changed to something else. For example:

> Thanks for your patience during these renovations. <sup>OK</sup>
>
> Thanks for your patience over these renovations. <sup>No</sup>
>
> Thanks for your patience over the course of these renovations.
>   <sup>Yes</sup>
>
> Thanks for your patience in these renovations. <sup>No</sup>
>
> Thanks for your patience in the midst of these renovations. <sup>Yes</sup>
>
> Thanks for your support in this campaign. <sup>Yes</sup>
>
> Thanks for your support over this campaign. <sup>marginal</sup>
>
> Thanks for your support over the length of this campaign.<sup>Yes</sup>
>
> Thanks for your support during this campaign. <sup>Yes</sup>

Comment: Thanks. Is there any particular situation or context in which we can only use during with like the past 2 years?